# More readable way to compare variable to list of values in if statement?

Tags: c, variables, if-statement

How can I compare a variable to a list of values of the same type in an `if` statement and make it readable and clean?

For example, I have the following, but there are a lot of values, and I want to make it more readable.

```
if ((lst->type == 'p' || lst->type == 'x' || lst->type == 'X' ||
    lst->type == 'o' || lst->type == 'O' || (lst->type == 'd' ||
    lst->type == 'i' || lst->type == 'D'))
```

Comment: `if` operator? OK....

Comment: _"to make it more readable"_, just put in some line breaks, and align the different possibilities. Also, your extra nested set of `()` is pointless. Or `switch` and `case` can also work in similar situations, albeit maybe not this.

Comment: A fall-through `switch` case is an option, but I wonder if that would be any _better_.

Comment: Treat a string type "pxXoOdiD" and do a look up on the string to find if `lst->type` contains the value using `strstr` function.

Comment: `bool do_stuff=false; for(size_t i=0; i<sizeof (TABLE)/sizeof(int); i++) { if(lst->type == TABLE[i]){ do_stuff=true; break;} }`

Comment: What Lundin said. And even better, write the loop in a utility function that has a decent name.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Easiest way to handle this using the `strchr` function:

```
const char *lookups = "pxXoOdiD";
if (strchr(lookups, lst->type)){ 
    // Do your thing here to handle the condition
}
```

More information about [strchr](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strchr/) can be found.

> Returns a pointer to the first occurrence of character in the C string str.

Answer (score 1):

Either use a lookup table, or use the `switch` statement:

```
const char lookup[] = {'p', 'x', 'X', 'o', 'O', 'd', 'i', 'D'};
for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(lookup)/sizeof(*lookup); i++){
    if (lst->type == lookup[i]) {
        // Your stuff
        break; // Remember to break
    }
}
```

```
switch (lst->type) {
    case 'p': case 'x': case 'X': case 'o':
    case 'O': case 'd': case 'i': case 'D':
        // Your stuff
}
```